# Вытащить id с тега input Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

блок выводит значение из базы данных. После выбора значения хочу вытащить id.

```
    <div class="block">

             <label>Refer</label> <select ng-controller="selectRefer">
                 <option ng-repeat="ref in refer">{{ref.refer}}</option>
             </select>
             <button ng-click="MyFunction()"> - </button> //тут я бы хотел через ng-click изьять 
                                  //данные из тега select и передать в 
                                  //контроллер и 
         </div>
```

контроллер что выводит

```
 selectInfo.controller('selectRefer', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, 
 $http) {
   $http({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'mysite',
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
      // Store response data
    $scope.refer = response.data;
     $scope.id = response.id
});
```

}]);

Как вытащить id из тега options по нажатию на кнопку -, я что то не допонимаю.

Comment: Возможно, я чего-то не понимаю в Вашей задаче, но почему просто не назначить этому селекту модель? (`ng-model=...`)

Comment: Ы нем будет хранится сразу значение и ид?

Comment: Конкретно в вашем примере - никак. Потому что кнопка создается за пределами контроллера `selectRefer`.